# Priority queue in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I am looking for a .NET implementation of a priority queue or heap data structure

> Priority queues are data structures that provide more flexibility than simple sorting, because they allow new elements to enter a system at arbitrary intervals. It is much more cost-effective to insert a new job into a priority queue than to re-sort everything on each such arrival.
>
> The basic priority queue supports three primary operations:
>
> - Insert(Q,x). Given an item x with key k, insert it into the priority queue Q.
> - Find-Minimum(Q). Return a pointer to the item
>   whose key value is smaller than any other key in the priority queue
>   Q.
> - Delete-Minimum(Q). Remove the item from the priority queue Q whose key is minimum

Unless I am looking in the wrong place, there isn't one in the framework. Is anyone aware of a good one, or should I roll my own?

Comment: You may find useful this implementation:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126751/Priority-queue-in-Csharp-with-help-of-heap-data-st.aspx it is generic and based on heap data structure

Comment: Here is the another implementation from NGenerics team: [NGenerics PriorityQueue](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/wiki/PriorityQueue)

Comment: FYI I've developed an **easy-to-use, highly optimized C# priority-queue, which can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/BlueRaja/high-speed-priority-queue-for-c)**.  It was developed specifically for pathfinding applications (A\*, etc.), but should work perfectly for any other application as well.  I would post this as an answer, but the question has recently been closed...

Comment: ParallelExtensionsExtras has a ConcurrentPriorityQueue http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples

Comment: Shamelessly introduce [PriorityQueue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net-threading/blob/master/src/Spring/Spring.Threading/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs), as part of effort to port java concurrent API to .net for Spring.Net. It's both a heap and queue with full generic support. Binary can be downloaded [here](https://code.google.com/p/netconcurrent/downloads/detail?name=Spring.Threading.1_0_0_M2.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Could you add that an an answer?

Comment: Just to summarize. There're no heap data structure in .net, neither in .net core now. Though [Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) users it for large numbers. [Internal implementations](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Shared/MS/Internal/PriorityQueue.cs,d4b2a99f94d0556e) exist.

Comment: Here's another .Net implementation (C# and F#)  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Net-Implementation-of-a-d3ac7b9d#content

Comment: @Artyom That internal implementation has been shown to have a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44221454/3546415

Comment: MS did implement a PriorityQueue it is just not public..  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Shared/MS/Internal/PriorityQueue.cs

Comment: Priority queue with SortedSet which allows duplicates https://yogeshdorbala.wordpress.com/2021/02/07/c-priority-queue-with-sortedset/

Comment: As of January 2021, .Net Core added a public PriorityQueue implementation. The actual commit to the repo and the API can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/826aa4f7844fd3d48784025ec6d47010867baab4

Comment: **.NET core 6.0** has a built-in [**PriorityQueue**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0). It's source can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I like using the `OrderedBag` and `OrderedSet` classes in [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) as priority queues.

Comment: OrderedBag/OrderedSet do more work than necessary, they use a red-black tree instead of a heap.

Comment: @DanBerindei: not necessary work if you need make running calculation (delete old items), heap only support deleting min or max

Comment: As with .NET 6, there is a built-in PriorityQueue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2

Answer (score 75):

You might like IntervalHeap from the [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/). To quote the [user guide](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/latest/ITU-TR-2006-76.pdf)

> Class `IntervalHeap<T>` implements interface `IPriorityQueue<T>` using an interval heap stored as an array of pairs. The `FindMin` and
> `FindMax` operations, and the indexer’s get-accessor, take time O(1). The `DeleteMin`,
> `DeleteMax`, Add and Update operations, and the indexer’s set-accessor, take time
> O(log n). In contrast to an ordinary priority queue, an interval heap offers both minimum
> and maximum operations with the same efficiency.

The API is simple enough

```
> var heap = new C5.IntervalHeap<int>();
> heap.Add(10);
> heap.Add(5);
> heap.FindMin();
5
```

Install from Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/C5 or GitHub  https://github.com/sestoft/C5/

Comment: This looks to be a very solid library and it comes with 1400 unit tests.

Comment: I tried to use it but it has serious flaws. IntervalHeap does not have a built-in concept of priority and forces you to implement IComparable or IComparer making it a sorted collection not a "Priority". Even worse there is no direct way to update priority of some previous entry!!!

Answer (score 57):

Here's my attempt at a .NET heap

```
public abstract class Heap<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private const int InitialCapacity = 0;
    private const int GrowFactor = 2;
    private const int MinGrow = 1;

    private int _capacity = InitialCapacity;
    private T[] _heap = new T[InitialCapacity];
    private int _tail = 0;

    public int Count { get { return _tail; } }
    public int Capacity { get { return _capacity; } }

    protected Comparer<T> Comparer { get; private set; }
    protected abstract bool Dominates(T x, T y);

    protected Heap() : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    protected Heap(Comparer<T> comparer) : this(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), comparer)
    {
    }

    protected Heap(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : this(collection, Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    protected Heap(IEnumerable<T> collection, Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
        if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");

        Comparer = comparer;

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (Count == Capacity)
                Grow();

            _heap[_tail++] = item;
        }

        for (int i = Parent(_tail - 1); i >= 0; i--)
            BubbleDown(i);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (Count == Capacity)
            Grow();

        _heap[_tail++] = item;
        BubbleUp(_tail - 1);
    }

    private void BubbleUp(int i)
    {
        if (i == 0 || Dominates(_heap[Parent(i)], _heap[i])) 
            return; //correct domination (or root)

        Swap(i, Parent(i));
        BubbleUp(Parent(i));
    }

    public T GetMin()
    {
        if (Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Heap is empty");
        return _heap[0];
    }

    public T ExtractDominating()
    {
        if (Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Heap is empty");
        T ret = _heap[0];
        _tail--;
        Swap(_tail, 0);
        BubbleDown(0);
        return ret;
    }

    private void BubbleDown(int i)
    {
        int dominatingNode = Dominating(i);
        if (dominatingNode == i) return;
        Swap(i, dominatingNode);
        BubbleDown(dominatingNode);
    }

    private int Dominating(int i)
    {
        int dominatingNode = i;
        dominatingNode = GetDominating(YoungChild(i), dominatingNode);
        dominatingNode = GetDominating(OldChild(i), dominatingNode);

        return dominatingNode;
    }

    private int GetDominating(int newNode, int dominatingNode)
    {
        if (newNode < _tail && !Dominates(_heap[dominatingNode], _heap[newNode]))
            return newNode;
        else
            return dominatingNode;
    }

    private void Swap(int i, int j)
    {
        T tmp = _heap[i];
        _heap[i] = _heap[j];
        _heap[j] = tmp;
    }

    private static int Parent(int i)
    {
        return (i + 1)/2 - 1;
    }

    private static int YoungChild(int i)
    {
        return (i + 1)*2 - 1;
    }

    private static int OldChild(int i)
    {
        return YoungChild(i) + 1;
    }

    private void Grow()
    {
        int newCapacity = _capacity*GrowFactor + MinGrow;
        var newHeap = new T[newCapacity];
        Array.Copy(_heap, newHeap, _capacity);
        _heap = newHeap;
        _capacity = newCapacity;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _heap.Take(Count).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class MaxHeap<T> : Heap<T>
{
    public MaxHeap()
        : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public MaxHeap(Comparer<T> comparer)
        : base(comparer)
    {
    }

    public MaxHeap(IEnumerable<T> collection, Comparer<T> comparer)
        : base(collection, comparer)
    {
    }

    public MaxHeap(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {
    }

    protected override bool Dominates(T x, T y)
    {
        return Comparer.Compare(x, y) >= 0;
    }
}

public class MinHeap<T> : Heap<T>
{
    public MinHeap()
        : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public MinHeap(Comparer<T> comparer)
        : base(comparer)
    {
    }

    public MinHeap(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public MinHeap(IEnumerable<T> collection, Comparer<T> comparer)
        : base(collection, comparer)
    {
    }

    protected override bool Dominates(T x, T y)
    {
        return Comparer.Compare(x, y) <= 0;
    }
}
```

Some tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class HeapTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestHeapBySorting()
    {
        var minHeap = new MinHeap<int>(new[] {9, 8, 4, 1, 6, 2, 7, 4, 1, 2});
        AssertHeapSort(minHeap, minHeap.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray());

        minHeap = new MinHeap<int> { 7, 5, 1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7 };
        AssertHeapSort(minHeap, minHeap.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray());

        var maxHeap = new MaxHeap<int>(new[] {1, 5, 3, 2, 7, 56, 3, 1, 23, 5, 2, 1});
        AssertHeapSort(maxHeap, maxHeap.OrderBy(d => -d).ToArray());

        maxHeap = new MaxHeap<int> {2, 6, 1, 3, 56, 1, 4, 7, 8, 23, 4, 5, 7, 34, 1, 4};
        AssertHeapSort(maxHeap, maxHeap.OrderBy(d => -d).ToArray());
    }

    private static void AssertHeapSort(Heap<int> heap, IEnumerable<int> expected)
    {
        var sorted = new List<int>();
        while (heap.Count > 0)
            sorted.Add(heap.ExtractDominating());

        Assert.IsTrue(sorted.SequenceEqual(expected));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend clearing the heap value in ExtractDominating, so it doesn't hold on to the referenced object longer than necessary (potential memory leak). For value types it obviously is of no concern.

Comment: Nice but you can't remove items from it? That's an important operation for priority queues.

Comment: It looks like the underlying object is an array. Wouldn't this be better as a binary tree?

Comment: @OhadSchneider very very cool, I was just looking into min heap and tried to do what you did making it generic and min or max heap! great work

Comment: I did not find the GetMax() ExtractTop() GetTop() functions.

Comment: @JaydeepShil the methods are called `ExtractDominating` and `GetDominating` - though you can add the methods you named as aliases for these in the subclasses (actually not a bad idea).

Comment: @OhadSchneider why didn't you use IEqualityComparer and you use Comparer?

Comment: @Gilad `IEqualityComparer<T>` wouldn't be enough, as that would only tell you whether two items are equal, whereas you need to know the relation between them (who's smaller / larger). It's true that I could have used `IComparer<T>` though...

Comment: Array.Copy(_heap, newHeap, _capacity); sounds like Grow() scales as O(n^2) instead of O(n)

Comment: Also the Heap should have always at the top the max/min element, so GetDominating() is doing more work than needed

Answer (score 25):

**.NET 6+:** As @rustyx commented, .NET 6 adds a [System.Collections.Generic.PriorityQueue<TElement,TPriority>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0) class. And FWIW it is open-source and [implemented in c#](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs).

**Earlier .NET Core versions and .NET Framework:** Microsoft has written (and shared online) [2 internal PriorityQueue classes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=priorityqueue) within the .NET Framework. However, as @mathusum-mut commented, there is a bug in one of them (the SO community has, of course, provided fixes for it): [Bug in Microsoft's internal PriorityQueue<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44221454/704808)

Comment: A bug was found in one of the implementations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221454/bug-in-microsofts-internal-priorityqueuet

Comment: ohh! I can see that all these classes `PriorityQueue<T>` in shared source of Microsoft are marked with `internal` access specifier. So they are used only by the internal functionalities of the framework. They aren't available for general consumption just by referring `windowsbase.dll` in a C# project. Only way is to copy the shared source into project itself inside a class file.

Answer (score 24):

here's one i just wrote, maybe it's not as optimized (just uses a sorted dictionary) but simple to understand.
you can insert objects of different kinds, so no generic queues.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PrioQueue
{
    public class PrioQueue
    {
        int total_size;
        SortedDictionary<int, Queue> storage;

        public PrioQueue ()
        {
            this.storage = new SortedDictionary<int, Queue> ();
            this.total_size = 0;
        }

        public bool IsEmpty ()
        {
            return (total_size == 0);
        }

        public object Dequeue ()
        {
            if (IsEmpty ()) {
                throw new Exception ("Please check that priorityQueue is not empty before dequeing");
            } else
                foreach (Queue q in storage.Values) {
                    // we use a sorted dictionary
                    if (q.Count > 0) {
                        total_size--;
                        return q.Dequeue ();
                    }
                }

                Debug.Assert(false,"not supposed to reach here. problem with changing total_size");

                return null; // not supposed to reach here.
        }

        // same as above, except for peek.

        public object Peek ()
        {
            if (IsEmpty ())
                throw new Exception ("Please check that priorityQueue is not empty before peeking");
            else
                foreach (Queue q in storage.Values) {
                    if (q.Count > 0)
                        return q.Peek ();
                }

                Debug.Assert(false,"not supposed to reach here. problem with changing total_size");

                return null; // not supposed to reach here.
        }

        public object Dequeue (int prio)
        {
            total_size--;
            return storage[prio].Dequeue ();
        }

        public void Enqueue (object item, int prio)
        {
            if (!storage.ContainsKey (prio)) {
                storage.Add (prio, new Queue ());
              }
            storage[prio].Enqueue (item);
            total_size++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt allow for multiple entries with the same priority though?

Comment: it does. when you invoke the Enqueue method, it will add the item to the queue of that priority. (the part in else in the enqueue method.)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not really a priority queue in the computer science meaning"? What about it makes you believe that this isn't a priority queue?

Comment: -1 for not using generics.

Comment: letsealunch, each priority has a queue of its own, so the queue just adds as many objects as you want.
when taking an object, we iterate the list of queues, looking at the count. so this is the only place where it's o(n) but n is just the number of the queues so that's not alot.
everything else is O(1) owing to: dictionary lookup, dequeue, and list.count method.
Since it's a sorted dictionary, the list is probably a balanced tree, but this only takes care of the keys.
and it's a simple solution, in my opinion.

Comment: One of the biggest benefits of Heap/PriorityQueue is the O(1) complexity of min/max extraction, i.e. the Peek operation. And here it involves enumerator setup, for-loop, etc. Why!?
Also, the "Enqueue" operation rather than being O(logN) - another key feature of the heap, has one O(longN) swipe because of "ContainsKey", a second one (again O(longN)) to add the Queue entry (if needed), a third one to actually retrieve the Queue (the storage[prio] line), and finally a linear adding to that queue. This is truly insane in the light of core algorithm implementation.

Comment: Hello Ivan, this is really old, but anyway: the implementation should be quite fast, queue operations are O(1) I think it's doubly linked list underneath, and dictionary is 0(1) too. SortedDictionary, I think they have a btree underneath, so o(logn) I guess, but i'm not sure about that. The only iterating is the foreach to get to the next queue. that length is quite small, depending on how many priorities you have. maybe 3, maybe 10 ? so not as bad as you think... and it's quite easy to understand owing to the light structure.

Comment: " so this is the only place where it's o(n) but n is just the number of the queues so that's not alot." -- That's quite an assumption. The priorities could be timestamps or other unique or near-unique values.

Comment: Jim Balter: no, the priorities are int. 0 - 100 or 0-255 can be enough for many uses.
 but i didn't put a limit there (int32).
can also use negative

Comment: Dequeue priority operation should have a size check condition.

Comment: @JonanGeorgiev what makes you think that the current implementation of Peek is O(logN)? It is O(1). You say that Enqueue operation has a linear time complexity when adding to the queue. That's not true. It's O(1) when enqueuing to the queue. However, ContainsKey is O(logN) as you mentioned, and hence it is a O(logN) in total.

Answer (score 11):

I found one by Julian Bucknall on his blog here - http://www.boyet.com/Articles/PriorityQueueCSharp3.html

We modified it slightly so that low-priority items on the queue would eventually 'bubble-up' to the top over time, so they wouldn't suffer starvation.

Answer (score 7):

```
class PriorityQueue<T>
{
    IComparer<T> comparer;
    T[] heap;
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public PriorityQueue() : this(null) { }
    public PriorityQueue(int capacity) : this(capacity, null) { }
    public PriorityQueue(IComparer<T> comparer) : this(16, comparer) { }
    public PriorityQueue(int capacity, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        this.comparer = (comparer == null) ? Comparer<T>.Default : comparer;
        this.heap = new T[capacity];
    }
    public void push(T v)
    {
        if (Count >= heap.Length) Array.Resize(ref heap, Count * 2);
        heap[Count] = v;
        SiftUp(Count++);
    }
    public T pop()
    {
        var v = top();
        heap[0] = heap[--Count];
        if (Count > 0) SiftDown(0);
        return v;
    }
    public T top()
    {
        if (Count > 0) return heap[0];
        throw new InvalidOperationException("优先队列为空");
    }
    void SiftUp(int n)
    {
        var v = heap[n];
        for (var n2 = n / 2; n > 0 && comparer.Compare(v, heap[n2]) > 0; n = n2, n2 /= 2) heap[n] = heap[n2];
        heap[n] = v;
    }
    void SiftDown(int n)
    {
        var v = heap[n];
        for (var n2 = n * 2; n2 < Count; n = n2, n2 *= 2)
        {
            if (n2 + 1 < Count && comparer.Compare(heap[n2 + 1], heap[n2]) > 0) n2++;
            if (comparer.Compare(v, heap[n2]) >= 0) break;
            heap[n] = heap[n2];
        }
        heap[n] = v;
    }
}
```

easy.

Comment: Sometimes I see stuff like

`for (var n2 = n / 2; n > 0 && comparer.Compare(v, heap[n2]) > 0; n = n2, n2 /= 2) heap[n] = heap[n2];`

and wonder if it was worth one-lining

Comment: @DustinBreakey personal style :)

Comment: but definitely not readable to others. Consider writing code which does not leave a question mark floating on top of the developer's head.

Comment: Make more readable

Answer (score 7):

### AlgoKit

I wrote an open source library called [AlgoKit](https://github.com/pgolebiowski/algo-kit), available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AlgoKit). It contains:

- **Implicit d-ary heaps** (ArrayHeap),
- **Binomial heaps**,
- **Pairing heaps**.

The code has been extensively tested. I definitely recommend you to give it a try.

### Example

```
var comparer = Comparer<int>.Default;
var heap = new PairingHeap<int, string>(comparer);

heap.Add(3, "your");
heap.Add(5, "of");
heap.Add(7, "disturbing.");
heap.Add(2, "find");
heap.Add(1, "I");
heap.Add(6, "faith");
heap.Add(4, "lack");

while (!heap.IsEmpty)
    Console.WriteLine(heap.Pop().Value);
```

### Why those three heaps?

The optimal choice of implementation is strongly input-dependent — as Larkin, Sen, and Tarjan show in *A back-to-basics empirical study of priority queues*, [arXiv:1403.0252v1 [cs.DS]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0252v1). They tested implicit d-ary heaps, pairing heaps, Fibonacci heaps, binomial heaps, explicit d-ary heaps, rank-pairing heaps, quake heaps, violation heaps, rank-relaxed weak heaps, and strict Fibonacci heaps.

AlgoKit features three types of heaps that appeared to be most efficient among those tested.

### Hint on choice

For a relatively small number of elements, you would likely be interested in using implicit heaps, especially quaternary heaps (implicit 4-ary). In case of operating on larger heap sizes, amortized structures like binomial heaps and pairing heaps should perform better.

Answer (score 4):

A Simple Max Heap Implementation.

https://github.com/bharathkumarms/AlgorithmsMadeEasy/blob/master/AlgorithmsMadeEasy/MaxHeap.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace AlgorithmsMadeEasy
{
    class MaxHeap
    {
        private static int capacity = 10;
        private int size = 0;
        int[] items = new int[capacity];

        private int getLeftChildIndex(int parentIndex) { return 2 * parentIndex + 1; }
        private int getRightChildIndex(int parentIndex) { return 2 * parentIndex + 2; }
        private int getParentIndex(int childIndex) { return (childIndex - 1) / 2; }

        private int getLeftChild(int parentIndex) { return this.items[getLeftChildIndex(parentIndex)]; }
        private int getRightChild(int parentIndex) { return this.items[getRightChildIndex(parentIndex)]; }
        private int getParent(int childIndex) { return this.items[getParentIndex(childIndex)]; }

        private bool hasLeftChild(int parentIndex) { return getLeftChildIndex(parentIndex) < size; }
        private bool hasRightChild(int parentIndex) { return getRightChildIndex(parentIndex) < size; }
        private bool hasParent(int childIndex) { return getLeftChildIndex(childIndex) > 0; }

        private void swap(int indexOne, int indexTwo)
        {
            int temp = this.items[indexOne];
            this.items[indexOne] = this.items[indexTwo];
            this.items[indexTwo] = temp;
        }

        private void hasEnoughCapacity()
        {
            if (this.size == capacity)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref this.items,capacity*2);
                capacity *= 2;
            }
        }

        public void Add(int item)
        {
            this.hasEnoughCapacity();
            this.items[size] = item;
            this.size++;
            heapifyUp();
        }

        public int Remove()
        {
            int item = this.items[0];
            this.items[0] = this.items[size-1];
            this.items[this.size - 1] = 0;
            size--;
            heapifyDown();
            return item;
        }

        private void heapifyUp()
        {
            int index = this.size - 1;
            while (hasParent(index) && this.items[index] > getParent(index))
            {
                swap(index, getParentIndex(index));
                index = getParentIndex(index);
            }
        }

        private void heapifyDown()
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (hasLeftChild(index))
            {
                int bigChildIndex = getLeftChildIndex(index);
                if (hasRightChild(index) && getLeftChild(index) < getRightChild(index))
                {
                    bigChildIndex = getRightChildIndex(index);
                }

                if (this.items[bigChildIndex] < this.items[index])
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    swap(bigChildIndex,index);
                    index = bigChildIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
Calling Code:
    MaxHeap mh = new MaxHeap();
    mh.Add(10);
    mh.Add(5);
    mh.Add(2);
    mh.Add(1);
    mh.Add(50);
    int maxVal  = mh.Remove();
    int newMaxVal = mh.Remove();
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a Java to C# translator on the Java implementation (java.util.PriorityQueue) in the Java Collections framework, or more intelligently use the algorithm and core code and plug it into a C# class of your own making that adheres to the C# Collections framework API for Queues, or at least Collections.

Comment: This works, but unfortunately IKVM doesn't support Java generics, so you lose type safety.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Java generics" when you're dealing with compiled Java bytecode. IKVM can't support it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and ended up creating a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MedallionPriorityQueue/) for this.

This implements a standard heap-based priority queue. It also has all the usual niceties of the BCL collections: `ICollection<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` implementation, custom `IComparer<T>` support, ability to specify an initial capacity, and a `DebuggerTypeProxy` to make the collection easier to work with in the debugger.

There is also an [Inline](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MedallionPriorityQueue.Inline/) version of the package which just installs a single .cs file into your project (useful if you want to avoid taking externally-visible dependencies).

More information is available on the [github page](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionUtilities/tree/master/MedallionPriorityQueue).

Answer (score -4):

The following implementation of a `PriorityQueue` uses `SortedSet` from the System library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CDiggins
{
    interface IPriorityQueue<T, K> where K : IComparable<K>
    {
        bool Empty { get; }
        void Enqueue(T x, K key);
        void Dequeue();
        T Top { get; }
    }

    class PriorityQueue<T, K> : IPriorityQueue<T, K> where K : IComparable<K>
    {
        SortedSet<Tuple<T, K>> set;

        class Comparer : IComparer<Tuple<T, K>> {
            public int Compare(Tuple<T, K> x, Tuple<T, K> y) {
                return x.Item2.CompareTo(y.Item2);
            }
        }

        PriorityQueue() { set = new SortedSet<Tuple<T, K>>(new Comparer()); }
        public bool Empty { get { return set.Count == 0;  } }
        public void Enqueue(T x, K key) { set.Add(Tuple.Create(x, key)); }
        public void Dequeue() { set.Remove(set.Max); }
        public T Top { get { return set.Max.Item1; } }
    }
}
```

Comment: SortedSet.Add will fail (and return false) if you already have an item in the set with the same "priority" as the item you are trying to add. So...if A.Compare(B) == 0 and A is already in the list, your PriorityQueue.Enqueue function will silently fail.

Comment: Mind to explain what are `T x` and `K key` ? I'm guessing this is a trick to allowing duplicate `T x`, and I need to generate an unique key (e.g. UUID) ?