# Fibonacci, Binary, or Binomial heap in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

Are there any heap data structure implementations out there, fibonacci, binary, or binomial?

Reference:  These are data structures used to implement priority queues, not the ones used to allocate dynamic memory.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13776636/67824

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net

Comment: You may be interested in [this NuGet package](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionUtilities/tree/master/MedallionPriorityQueue), which implements a priority queue based on a binary heap.

Comment: [Off Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Some questions are still off-topic, … 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* - that reduces on-topic answers to `yes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any native framework implementation.

I found two implementations of binary heap ([link 1](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidA3988613D26F26CB5D806CF1FD320C0FDA54C389.aspx?s=file:semaphore.cs), [link 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2005/02/13/371719.aspx)) and one implementation of binomial heap in f# ([link](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/244.aspx)).

Answer (score 8):

Free C# implementation of heaps and many other data structures:

- [The C5 Generic Collection Library for C# and CLI](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/)
- [Wintellect's Power Collections for .NET](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=6863)

Answer (score 5):

[QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) implements Fibonacci Heaps and Queues in C#, among a whole lot of other stuff. It is free and open-source.

Comment: Documentation for QuickGraph is difficult to parse if you're just looking for a fib heap.  Source code also isn't very clear. :(

Answer (score 5):

Stand alone stress tested implementations are in Github under [Advanced-Algorithms](https://github.com/justcoding121/Advanced-Algorithms) repository. DecrementKey operation performance is what makes later two significant.

- Binary Min/Max Heap
- Binomial Min/Max Heap
- Fibonacci Min/Max Heap

The repository has two more heap implementations, D-Ary Heap & Pairing Heap.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` with a custom `Comparer` will do the job.

The `Comparer` will look like the following:

```
class KeyValueComparer<K, V> : IComparer<KeyValuePair<K,V>> where K:IComparable where V:IComparable
{
    public int Compare(KeyValuePair<K, V> x, KeyValuePair<K, V> y)
    {
        var res = x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
        return res == 0 ? x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value) : res;
    }
}
```

With such `Comparer`, the `SortedSet` will be sorted by Key and it will allow duplicates of keys.

You can get the `Min` at constant time, `RemoveMin` at `O(logn)`, `Add` an entry at `O(logn)` and `Update` a key at `O(logn)`.

Here is a full (or almost) implementation:

```
public class Heap<K, V>
    where K : IComparable
    where V : IComparable
{
    private readonly SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K, V>> _sortedSet;

    // O(1)
    public KeyValuePair<K, V> Min
    {
        get { return _sortedSet.Min; }
    }

    public Heap()
    {
        _sortedSet = new SortedSet<KeyValuePair<K, V>>(new KeyValueComparer<K, V>());
    } 

    // O(logn)
    public void Add(K key, V value)
    {
        _sortedSet.Add(new KeyValuePair<K, V>(key, value));
    }

    // O(logn)
    public KeyValuePair<K, V> RemoveMin()
    {
        var min = Min;
        _sortedSet.Remove(min);
        return min;
    }

    // O(logn)
    public void Remove(K key, V value)
    {
        _sortedSet.Remove(new KeyValuePair<K, V>(key, value));
    }

    // O(logn)
    public void UpdateKey(K oldKey, V oldValue, K newKey)
    {
        Remove(oldKey, oldValue);
        Add(newKey, oldValue);
    }

    private class KeyValueComparer<K, V> : IComparer<KeyValuePair<K, V>>
        where K : IComparable
        where V : IComparable
    {
        public int Compare(KeyValuePair<K, V> x, KeyValuePair<K, V> y)
        {
            var res = x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
            return res == 0 ? x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value) : res;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to wikipedia, using Fibonacci or pairing heap you could get O(1) for insertion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap#Summary_of_running_times

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of MinHeap and MaxHeap:

```
public abstract class Heap<T>
{
    private List<T> m_Vector;

    private void Swap(int i, int j)
    {
        var tmp = m_Vector[i];
        m_Vector[i] = m_Vector[j];
        m_Vector[j] = tmp;
    }

    protected abstract int Compare(T a, T b);

    private void SiftUp(int i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        int parent = (i - 1) / 2;

        if (Compare(m_Vector[i], m_Vector[parent]) >= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Swap(i, parent);
        SiftUp(parent);
    }

    private void SiftDown(int i)
    {
        int left = i * 2 + 1;

        if (left >= m_Vector.Count)
        {
            return;
        }

        var right = left + 1;

        var child = left;

        if (right < m_Vector.Count)
        {
            if (Compare(m_Vector[left], m_Vector[right]) > 0)
            {
                child = right;
            }
        }

        if (Compare(m_Vector[i], m_Vector[child]) <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Swap(i, child);
        SiftDown(child);
    }

    public Heap()
    {
        m_Vector = new List<T>();
    }

    public Heap(IEnumerable<T> elements)
    {
        m_Vector = new List<T>(elements);

        if (m_Vector.Count < 2)
        {
            return;
        }

        //
        // From the last parent, upwards, sift down. Each sift is O<1>.
        //
        for (int i = (m_Vector.Count - 2) / 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            SiftDown(i);
        }
    }

    public int Count { get { return m_Vector.Count; } }

    public void Add(T element)
    {
        m_Vector.Add(element);
        SiftUp(m_Vector.Count - 1);
    }

    public T Top
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Vector.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            return m_Vector[0];
        }
    }

    public T Fetch()
    {
        if (m_Vector.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        T result = m_Vector[0];
        m_Vector[0] = m_Vector[m_Vector.Count - 1];
        m_Vector.RemoveAt(m_Vector.Count - 1);

        SiftDown(0);

        return result;
    }
}

public class MinHeap<T> : Heap<T> where T: IComparable 
{
    protected override int Compare(T a, T b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }

    public MinHeap() : base()
    {
    }

    public MinHeap(IEnumerable<T> elements) : base(elements)
    {
    }
}

public class MaxHeap<T> : Heap<T> where T : IComparable
{
    protected override int Compare(T a, T b)
    {
        return b.CompareTo(a);
    }

    public MaxHeap() : base()
    {
    }

    public MaxHeap(IEnumerable<T> elements) : base(elements)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Simple Min Heap Implementation.

https://github.com/bharathkumarms/AlgorithmsMadeEasy/blob/master/AlgorithmsMadeEasy/MinHeap.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace AlgorithmsMadeEasy
{
    public class MinHeap
    {
        private static int capacity = 10;
        private int size = 0;

        int[] items = new int[capacity];

        private int getLeftChildIndex(int parentIndex) { return 2*parentIndex+1 ; }
        private int getRightChildIndex(int parentIndex) { return 2*parentIndex+2 ; }
        private int getParentIndex(int childIndex) { return (childIndex - 1) / 2; }

        private bool hasLeftChild(int index) { return getLeftChildIndex(index) < size; }
        private bool hasRightChild(int index) { return getRightChildIndex(index) < this.size; }
        private bool hasParent(int index) { return getParentIndex(index) >= 0; }

        private int leftChild(int index) { return this.items[getLeftChildIndex(index)]; }
        private int rightChild(int index) { return this.items[getRightChildIndex(index)]; }
        private int parent(int index) { return this.items[this.getParentIndex(index)]; }

        private void swap(int indexOne, int indexTwo)
        {
            int temp = this.items[indexOne];
            this.items[indexOne] = this.items[indexTwo];
            this.items[indexTwo] = temp;
        }

        private void ensureExtraCapacity()
        {
            if (this.size == capacity)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref this.items, capacity*2);
                capacity *= 2;
            }
        }

        public int peek()
        {
            if(this.size==0) throw new NotSupportedException();
            return this.items[0];
        }

        public int remove()
        {
            if(this.size==0) throw new NotSupportedException();
            int item = this.items[0];
            items[0] = items[this.size - 1];
            items[this.size - 1] = 0;
            this.size--;
            heapifyDown();
            return item;
        }

        public void Add(int item)
        {
            this.ensureExtraCapacity();
            this.items[size] = item;
            this.size++;
            heapifyUp();
        }

        private void heapifyUp()
        {
            int index = this.size - 1;
            while (hasParent(index) && parent(index) > this.items[index])
            {
                swap(index,getParentIndex(index));
                index = getParentIndex(index);
            }
        }

        private void heapifyDown()
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (hasLeftChild(index))
            {
                int smallerChildIndex = getLeftChildIndex(index);
                if (hasRightChild(index) && rightChild(index) < leftChild(index))
                {
                    smallerChildIndex = getRightChildIndex(index);
                }

                if (this.items[index] < this.items[smallerChildIndex])
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    swap(index,smallerChildIndex);
                }
                index = smallerChildIndex;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
Calling Code:
    MinHeap mh = new MinHeap();
    mh.Add(10);
    mh.Add(5);
    mh.Add(2);
    mh.Add(1);
    mh.Add(50);
    int peek = mh.peek();
    mh.remove();
    int newPeek = mh.peek();
*/
```