# how can I convert C++ std::push_heap to C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I have some C++ code like this:

```
std::vector<PathNode> nodes;


PathNode node;
....
nodes.push_back(node);
std::push_heap(nodes.begin(), nodes.end());
```

Now I will rewrite these C++ code to C#, how can I implement the std::push_heap method?

Comment: `PathNode node = new PathNode();` That's not C++.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to explicitly convert each individual line of code from one language to another?  What makes sense in one language doesn't always make sense in another.  Step back and look at the overall functionality of your application.  What logic do you need the application to perform?

Comment: oh, sorry! I edited my question.

Comment: this is a pathfinding method from WarZone2100 [link](https://github.com/Warzone2100/warzone2100/blob/master/src/astar.cpp  , fpathNewNode method)  , I'll tring to rewrite the A* code to C#.

Comment: I didn't even know of the concept of *heap*. Very interesting.

Comment: There is no min/max heap "ordering" plus ancillary methods in the .NET . You'll have to build them or find a library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own comparison function for the PathNode

```
struct greaters{
  bool operator()(const PathNode& a,const PathNode& b) const{
    return a.x>b.x;
  }
};    

std::vector<PathNode> nodes;


PathNode node;

nodes.push_back(node);

std::make_heap(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), greaters()));
std::push_heap(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), greaters()));
```

For C#

You could use `SortedList` or a `SortedDictionary` with a custom key. If you used a type with referential equality, but could be compared based on the value you care about, then this could work.

[Heap class in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231796/heap-class-in-net/2231812)

Answer (score 0):

I used a general List<>, sorted when Insert:

```
static List<int> nodes = new List<int>();

static void Main()
{
    PushNode(3);
    PushNode(12);
    PushNode(4);
    PushNode(6);
    PushNode(5);
    PushNode(8);
    PushNode(2);
    PushNode(9);
    PushNode(1);

    foreach (int value in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

}

static void PushNode(int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (nodes[i] > value)
        {
            nodes.Insert(i, value);
            return;
        }
    }

    nodes.Add(value);
    return;

}
```