# Priority Queue in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, priority-queue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Priority queue in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net) is similar, but i want to exactly know:

Is there any class/struct/... in .Net for priority queue?  Just like in STL that have  `priority_queue` for this. It accepts a **comparsion** function to support customized sorts.

The best thing i found in .Net is **SortedList< Key, Value >** that sorts it's values by Key. So one solution is implementing a custom **Compare** interface for Key class. But i cannot seperate my elements into Key/Value pairs. I have atomic elements that must queued according to their values with a custom function.

So, is there any collection class in .Net that accepts a Compare function for sorting the it's elements?

Is there any way to derive a .Net class (maybe **HashSet**) that supports this feature?

---

#### Note:

- I know that many third-parties implemented really good classes for this. Maybe a good example is [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections). But i want t quick and simple solution using existing classes in .Net
- I am using .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: As of January 2021, .Net Core added a PriorityQueue implementation. The actual commit to the repo and the API can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/826aa4f7844fd3d48784025ec6d47010867baab4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) class, which is generic.

You can specify a comparer object to the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a045f865.aspx), which should handle the priority comparison of your objects:

```
public class DataComparer : IComparer<Data>
{
    public Int32 Compare(Data a, Data b)
    {
        if (a == null && b == null)
            return 0;
        if (a == null)
            return -1;
        if (b == null)
            return +1;
        return a.Priority.CompareTo(b.Priority);
    }
}

SortedDictionary<Data, Data> priQueue = new SortedDictionary<Data, Data>(
    new DataComparer());
```

Comment: It seems that i have to save my element (the `Data` class) twice. As i said, i don't have a Key/Value pair. I have atomic elements from `Data` and a `Compare` function/class/...

Comment: Shouldn't matter if the Data class is actually a class, it's only the reference you're storing twice. You could of course wrap that collection in one of your own, providing a leaner interface for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the Snippet Lasse, got distracted by a manager :)

Comment: Won't that fail if the priorities are equal?

Answer (score 1):

You could just implement IComparable on your class and create the specific comparer inside your class, that way you can just use IList.Sort() ?

Comment: This solution really works but have weak performance. When i insert/remove an element into/from the List, the sorted list will be ruined and because IList.Sort() it not "smart", i will have do more than a regular priority_queue

Comment: In that case, don't use IList, but implement an ICollection and you can specify your own Insert method that lets you order correctly on insertion.

Comment: @Ress C - 'ICollection' of 'List' class? Or using another class? can you provide a simple pseudocode? Thanks a lot!