# Sorting/Ordering a BlockingCollecion

Tags: c#, .net, blockingcollection

What would be the best way to sort the items in a `BlockingCollection<T>` based on their values in a particular order. I know there is an `OrderBy` method, can it be utilized to achieve ordering?

Comment: Why do you need to sort it?

Comment: @Dennis I need to sort the Queue based on a parameter so it is not first come first serve!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016509/concurrent-priority-queue-in-net-4-0

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to order the items in the queue according to some comparison criteria. That's basically a `Priority Queue`.

There is a way to use a priority queue with a `BlockingCollection<T>`. You have to write a `Priority Queue` that implements `IProducerConsumerCollection` and pass an instance of that queue to the appropriate `BlockingCollection` constructor.

Fortunately, Microsoft have provided [sample code that demonstrates how to do this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460690%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It also includes the source code for a simple priority queue.

There are many other priority queue implementations available on line, [for example here](http://www.vcskicks.com/priority-queue.php). You would, however, have to modify them to implement `IProducerConsumerCollection`, which is unlikely to be a trivial task.

[EDIT] I found a [concurrent priority queue that implements `IProducerConsumerCollection`](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/5C8EBB0B/7C14AFBD) - you should be able to use it.

Comment: that link doesn't work for concurrent priority queue.

Answer (score -1):

Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx

From MSDN:

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static void OrderByEx1()
{
    Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                   new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                   new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

    IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);

    foreach (Pet pet in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
    }
}

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 Whiskers - 1
 Boots - 4
 Barley - 8
*/
```

Comment: This will sort collection snapshot, not a collection itself. Looks like OP wants some priority so proceed collection items.

Comment: Is not possible to set the ordered collection to source?

Comment: `BlockingCollection<T>` is a *concurrent* collection for solving producer-consumer tasks. Any thread can modify it in thread-safe way. Re-sorting collection, re-assigning collection at least will lead to data loss.

Comment: @Dennis what are you suggesting to do in this case Dennis?

Comment: @TimeMachine: priority queue is what you need. You've got a number of links and answer already.