# Algorithm for N-way merge

Tags: algorithm, merge

A 2-way merge is widely studied as a part of Mergesort algorithm.
But I am interested to find out the best way one can perform an N-way merge?

Lets say, I have `N` files which have sorted 1 million integers each.
I have to merge them into 1 single file which will have those 100 million sorted integers.

Please keep in mind that use case for this problem is actually external sorting which is disk based. Therefore, in real scenarios there would be memory limitation as well. So a naive approach of merging 2 files at a time (99 times) won't work. Lets say we have only a small sliding window of memory available for each array.

I am not sure if there is already a standardized solution to this N-way merge. *(Googling didn't tell me much)*.

But if you know if a good n-way merge algorithm, please post algo/link.

**Time complexity:** If we greatly increase the number of files (`N`) to be merged, how would that affect the time complexity of your algorithm?

Thanks for your answers.

*I haven't been asked this anywhere, but I felt this could be an interesting interview question. Therefore tagged.*

Comment: Why won't the pairwise merge of files work?

Comment: For the record, this is known as balance line or k-way merge. Balance line algorithms usually have O(kn) time complexity where k is the number of files and n is the total number of items, whereas heap k-way merges are usually O(n log k). Both algorithms have O(k) space complexity.

Comment: @paul, ok I must admit that I was wrong when I said that merging 2 files at a time won't work due to space considerations. But in I think it would be a very slow algo, that is why it won't work.

Comment: @Bavarious can you say why you think merging like this is O(kn). It seems to me like it's O(n log k) (since merging each pair is O(n) and you have to do it O(log k) times to reduce down to a single file). It uses only O(1) space too.

Comment: @PaulHankin Balance line keeps an unsorted array (instead of a heap) with the last key read from each input file, hence k in both O(kn) and O(k). It is good enough for small k.

Comment: It's a favorite google interview question. Sort 2Gb file given you have 3Fb RAM.

Comment: According to http://cs.uno.edu/people/faculty/bill/k-way-merge-n-sort-ACM-SE-Regl-1993.pdf this approach requires fewer comparisons than the priority queue approach. I'll also mention that the priority queue approach is awful in Haskell, which is how I came to be searching for info on other ways.

Comment: [Here](http://www.sinbadsoft.com/blog/sorting-big-files-using-k-way-merge-sort/) is a simple external sort algo (k way merge sort based on a priority queue)

Comment: @zengr, you mean 3Mb RAM?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

How about the following idea:

1. Create a priority queue
2. Iterate through each file *f*

   1. enqueue the pair *(nextNumberIn(f), f)* using the first value as priority key
3. While queue not empty

   1. dequeue head *(m, f)* of queue
   2. output *m*
   3. if *f* not depleted

      1. enqueue *(nextNumberIn(f), f)*

Since adding elements to a priority queue can be done in logarithmic time, item 2 is *O(N × log N)*. Since (almost all) iterations of the while loop adds an element, the whole while-loop is *O(M × log N)* where *M* is the total number of numbers to sort.

Assuming all files have a non-empty sequence of numbers, we have *M > N* and thus the whole algorithm should be *O(M × log N)*.

Comment: Very neat. I was thinking on similar lines, except the pairing of number with file didn't occur to me. Thanks. Accepting.

Comment: @aioobe: Your soulution is neat but you are making a lot of read calls which can hurt efficiency. For example, in item 3, for every while iteration, you make a read call for the next element in f . I think it will be better if you change the if condition to follows: if f not present in queue and f not depleted. This way you will make a read only if no element of f is present in the queue. Moreover, when you do make this read, you can read a chunk of numbers in f at once.

Comment: "*if f not present in queue*", it's never present after dequeuing since there's always at most one value from each file present in the queue. Regarding your second comment: Your suggestion doesn't improve the complexity (except that it makes the answer more complex to read!) Besides, keep in mind that this is pseudo-code. It can very well be implemented with some buffered reader which reads larger chunks and caches them.

Comment: @aioobe but how would your method function with 100 million numbers? surely you can't bring them all into memory.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Where does it say that you should put everything into memory?

Comment: @aioobe: I did not understand the steps 2 and 3 clearly. Are you suggesting that in step 2 read all the file contents into the priority queue ? In step 3 did not understand why enqueue again while we have already read the whole content of file into the queue. Could you please elaborate, I did not understand this completely. Thanks.

Comment: @Programmer, I think you have a good point regarding number of reads, but you don't really have to implement "if f not present in queue"; you can simply buffer f and use aioobe's algorithm as is, reading the values of f through the buffer.

Comment: Srtictly saying, if you implement priority queue as heap, then complexity of initial creation of heap of N elements is _O(N)_. Though this doesn't impact overall estimate of merge complexity.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra, no, step two inserts *the first* number in each file. In step 3 (the while loop) a value is dequeued and the next value from that file is enqueued (unless that file is depleted). Still unclear?

Answer (score 13):

Search for "Polyphase merge", check out classics - Donald Knuth & E.H.Friend.

Also, you may want to take a look at the proposed *Smart Block Merging* by Seyedafsari & Hasanzadeh, that, similarly to earlier suggestions, uses priority queues.

Another interesting reasonsing is [*In Place Merging Algorithm*](http://www.springerlink.com/content/p01313286811q58j/) by Kim & Kutzner.

I also recommend this paper by Vitter: [External memory algorithms and data structures: dealing with massive data](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=384192.384193).

Comment: Your Smart Block Merging link is wrong.  It's some article about supply chains in Estonia.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for pointing it out. In 2012, the waset.org host seems to have overriden these files (originally, published in 2010) with new conference proceedings. I'm unable to locate the old article. If anybody has it, please post/link.

Comment: This is the new link: http://waset.org/publications/9638/optimal-external-merge-sorting-algorithm-with-smart-block-merging

Answer (score 6):

One simple idea is to keep a priority queue of the ranges to merge, stored in such a way that the range with the smallest first element is removed first from the queue.  You can then do an N-way merge as follows:

1. Insert all of the ranges into the priority queue, excluding empty ranges.
2. While the priority queue is not empty:

   1. Dequeue the smallest element from the queue.
   2. Append the first element of this range to the output sequence.
   3. If it's nonempty, insert the rest of the sequence back into the priority queue.

The correctness of this algorithm is essentially a generalization of the proof that a 2-way merge works correctly - if you always add the smallest element from any range, and all the ranges are sorted, you end up with the sequence as a whole sorted.

The runtime complexity of this algorithm can be found as follows.  Let M be the total number of elements in all the sequences.  If we use a binary heap, then we do at most O(M) insertions and O(M) deletions from the priority queue, since for each element written to the output sequence there's a dequeue to pull out the smallest sequence, followed by an enqueue to put the rest of the sequence back into the queue.  Each of these steps takes O(lg N) operations, because insertion or deletion from a binary heap with N elements in it takes O(lg N) time.  This gives a net runtime of O(M lg N), which grows less than linearly with the number of input sequences.

There may be a way to get this even faster, but this seems like a pretty good solution.  The memory usage is O(N) because we need O(N) overhead for the binary heap.  If we implement the binary heap by storing pointers to the sequences rather than the sequences themselves, this shouldn't be too much of a problem unless you have a truly ridiculous number of sequences to merge.  In that case, just merge them in groups that do fit into memory, then merge all the results.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach to Merging k sorted arrays (each of length n) requires O(n k^2) time and not O(nk) time.  As when you merge first 2 arrays it takes 2n time, then when you merge third with the output , it takes 3n time as now we are merging two array of length 2n and n. Now when we merge this output with the fourth one,this merge requires 4n time.Thus the last merge (when we are adding the kth array to our already sorted array ) requires k*n time.Thus total time required is 2n+ 3n + 4n +...k*n  which is    O(n k^2).

It looks like we can do it in O(kn) time but it is not so because each time our array which we are merging is increasing in size.
Though we can achieve a better bound using divide and conquer. I am still working on that and post a solution if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting. Here is my take on the heap based k-way merge, using a buffered read from the sources to emulate I/O reduction:

```cs
public class KWayMerger<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T[]> _sources;
    private readonly int _bufferSize;
    private readonly MinHeap<MergeValue<T>> _mergeHeap;
    private readonly int[] _indices;

    public KWayMerger(IList<T[]> sources, int bufferSize, Comparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (sources == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sources");

        _sources = sources;
        _bufferSize = bufferSize;

        _mergeHeap = new MinHeap<MergeValue<T>>(
                      new MergeComparer<T>(comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default));
        _indices = new int[sources.Count];
    }

    public T[] Merge()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= _sources.Count - 1; i++)
            AddToMergeHeap(i);

        var merged = new T[_sources.Sum(s => s.Length)];
        int mergeIndex = 0;

        while (_mergeHeap.Count > 0)
        {
            var min = _mergeHeap.ExtractDominating();
            merged[mergeIndex++] = min.Value;
            if (min.Source != -1) //the last item of the source was extracted
                AddToMergeHeap(min.Source);
        }

        return merged;
    }

    private void AddToMergeHeap(int sourceIndex)
    {
        var source = _sources[sourceIndex];
        var start = _indices[sourceIndex];
        var end = Math.Min(start + _bufferSize - 1, source.Length - 1);

        if (start > source.Length - 1)
            return; //we're done with this source

        for (int i = start; i <= end - 1; i++)
            _mergeHeap.Add(new MergeValue<T>(-1, source[i]));   

        //only the last item should trigger the next buffered read
        _mergeHeap.Add(new MergeValue<T>(sourceIndex, source[end]));

        _indices[sourceIndex] += _bufferSize; //we may have added less items, 
        //but if we did we've reached the end of the source so it doesn't matter
    } 
}

internal class MergeValue<T>
{
    public int Source { get; private set; }
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public MergeValue(int source, T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Source = source;
    }
}

internal class MergeComparer<T> : IComparer<MergeValue<T>>
{
    public Comparer<T> Comparer { get; private set; }

    public MergeComparer(Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
        Comparer = comparer;
    }

    public int Compare(MergeValue<T> x, MergeValue<T> y)
    {
        Debug.Assert(x != null && y != null);
        return Comparer.Compare(x.Value, y.Value);
    }
}
```

[Here is one possible implementation of `MinHeap<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13776636/67824). Some tests:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestKWaySort()
{
    var rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        AssertKwayMerge(rand);
}

private static void AssertKwayMerge(Random rand)
{
    var sources = new[]
        {
            GenerateRandomCollection(rand, 10, 30, 0, 30).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray(),
            GenerateRandomCollection(rand, 10, 30, 0, 30).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray(),
            GenerateRandomCollection(rand, 10, 30, 0, 30).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray(),
            GenerateRandomCollection(rand, 10, 30, 0, 30).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray(),
        };
    Assert.IsTrue(new KWayMerger<int>(sources, 20).Merge().SequenceEqual(sources.SelectMany(s => s).OrderBy(i => i)));
}

public static IEnumerable<int> GenerateRandomCollection(Random rand, int minLength, int maxLength, int min = 0, int max = int.MaxValue)
{
    return Enumerable.Repeat(0, rand.Next(minLength, maxLength)).Select(i => rand.Next(min, max));
}
```

Comment: What is the language of your code? (Sorry, I am new in programming; I am looking for a Java solution).

Comment: @Hengameh it's C#. The syntax is very similar to Java so it shouldn't be too hard to translate it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this STL-style piece of code that does N-way merge and thought I'd post it here to help prevent others from reinventing the wheel. :)

*Warning: it's only mildly tested. Test before use. :)*

You can use it like this:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > v;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> vout;
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v2.push_back(0);
    v2.push_back(1);
    v2.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(v1);
    v.push_back(v2);
    multiway_merge(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(vout), false);
}
```

It also allows using pairs of iterators instead of the containers themselves.

If you use Boost.Range, you can remove some of the boilerplate code.

The code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>  // std::less
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>  // std::priority_queue
#include <utility>  // std::pair
#include <vector>

template<class OutIt>
struct multiway_merge_value_insert_iterator : public std::iterator<
    std::output_iterator_tag, OutIt, ptrdiff_t
>
{
    OutIt it;
    multiway_merge_value_insert_iterator(OutIt const it = OutIt())
        : it(it) { }

    multiway_merge_value_insert_iterator &operator++(int)
    { return *this; }

    multiway_merge_value_insert_iterator &operator++()
    { return *this; }

    multiway_merge_value_insert_iterator &operator *()
    { return *this; }

    template<class It>
    multiway_merge_value_insert_iterator &operator =(It const i)
    {
        *this->it = *i;
        ++this->it;
        return *this;
    }
};

template<class OutIt>
multiway_merge_value_insert_iterator<OutIt>
    multiway_merge_value_inserter(OutIt const it)
{ return multiway_merge_value_insert_iterator<OutIt>(it); };

template<class Less>
struct multiway_merge_value_less : private Less
{
    multiway_merge_value_less(Less const &less) : Less(less) { }
    template<class It1, class It2>
    bool operator()(
        std::pair<It1, It1> const &b /* inverted */,
        std::pair<It2, It2> const &a) const
    {
        return b.first != b.second && (
            a.first == a.second ||
            this->Less::operator()(*a.first, *b.first));
    }
};

struct multiway_merge_default_less
{
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) const
    { return std::less<T>()(a, b); }
};

template<class R>
struct multiway_merge_range_iterator
{ typedef typename R::iterator type; };

template<class R>
struct multiway_merge_range_iterator<R const>
{ typedef typename R::const_iterator type; };

template<class It>
struct multiway_merge_range_iterator<std::pair<It, It> >
{ typedef It type; };

template<class R>
typename R::iterator multiway_merge_range_begin(R &r)
{ return r.begin(); }

template<class R>
typename R::iterator multiway_merge_range_end(R &r)
{ return r.end(); }

template<class R>
typename R::const_iterator multiway_merge_range_begin(R const &r)
{ return r.begin(); }

template<class R>
typename R::const_iterator multiway_merge_range_end(R const &r)
{ return r.end(); }

template<class It>
It multiway_merge_range_begin(std::pair<It, It> const &r)
{ return r.first; }

template<class It>
It multiway_merge_range_end(std::pair<It, It> const &r)
{ return r.second; }

template<class It, class OutIt, class Less, class PQ>
OutIt multiway_merge(
    It begin, It const end, OutIt out, Less const &less,
    PQ &pq, bool const distinct = false)
{
    while (begin != end)
    {
        pq.push(typename PQ::value_type(
            multiway_merge_range_begin(*begin),
            multiway_merge_range_end(*begin)));
        ++begin;
    }
    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        typename PQ::value_type top = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if (top.first != top.second)
        {
            while (!pq.empty() && pq.top().first == pq.top().second)
            { pq.pop(); }
            if (!distinct ||
                pq.empty() ||
                less(*pq.top().first, *top.first) ||
                less(*top.first, *pq.top().first))
            {
                *out = top.first;
                ++out;
            }

            ++top.first;
            pq.push(top);
        }
    }
    return out;
}

template<class It, class OutIt, class Less>
OutIt multiway_merge(
    It const begin, It const end, OutIt out, Less const &less,
    bool const distinct = false)
{
    typedef typename multiway_merge_range_iterator<
        typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
    >::type SubIt;
    if (std::distance(begin, end) < 16)
    {
        typedef std::vector<std::pair<SubIt, SubIt> > Remaining;
        Remaining remaining;
        remaining.reserve(
            static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(begin, end)));
        for (It i = begin; i != end; ++i)
        {
            if (multiway_merge_range_begin(*i) !=
                multiway_merge_range_end(*i))
            {
                remaining.push_back(std::make_pair(
                    multiway_merge_range_begin(*i),
                    multiway_merge_range_end(*i)));
            }
        }
        while (!remaining.empty())
        {
            typename Remaining::iterator smallest =
                remaining.begin();
            for (typename Remaining::iterator
                i = remaining.begin();
                i != remaining.end();
            )
            {
                if (less(*i->first, *smallest->first))
                {
                    smallest = i;
                    ++i;
                }
                else if (distinct && i != smallest &&
                    !less(
                        *smallest->first,
                        *i->first))
                {
                    i = remaining.erase(i);
                }
                else { ++i; }
            }
            *out = smallest->first;
            ++out;
            ++smallest->first;
            if (smallest->first == smallest->second)
            { smallest = remaining.erase(smallest); }
        }
        return out;
    }
    else
    {
        std::priority_queue<
            std::pair<SubIt, SubIt>,
            std::vector<std::pair<SubIt, SubIt> >,
            multiway_merge_value_less<Less>
        > q((multiway_merge_value_less<Less>(less)));
        return multiway_merge(begin, end, out, less, q, distinct);
    }
}

template<class It, class OutIt>
OutIt multiway_merge(
    It const begin, It const end, OutIt const out,
    bool const distinct = false)
{
    return multiway_merge(
        begin, end, out,
        multiway_merge_default_less(), distinct);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is my implementation using MinHeap...

package merging;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class N_Way_Merge {

int No_of_files=0;
String[] listString;
int[] listIndex;
PrintWriter pw;
private String fileDir = "D:\\XMLParsing_Files\\Extracted_Data";
private File[] fileList;
private BufferedReader[] readers;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    N_Way_Merge nwm=new N_Way_Merge();

    long start= System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {

        nwm.createFileList();

        nwm.createReaders();
        nwm.createMinHeap();
    }
    finally {
        nwm.pw.flush();
        nwm.pw.close();
        for (BufferedReader readers : nwm.readers) {

            readers.close();

        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Files merged into a single file.\nTime taken: "+((end-start)/1000)+"secs");
}

public void createFileList() throws IOException {
    //creates a list of sorted files present in a particular directory
    File folder = new File(fileDir);
    fileList = folder.listFiles();
    No_of_files=fileList.length;
    assign();
    System.out.println("No. of files - "+ No_of_files);

}

public void assign() throws IOException
{
    listString = new String[No_of_files];
    listIndex = new int[No_of_files];
    pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\XMLParsing_Files\\Final.txt", true)));
}

public void createReaders() throws IOException {
    //creates array of BufferedReaders to read the files
    readers = new BufferedReader[No_of_files];

    for(int i=0;i<No_of_files;++i)
    {
        readers[i]=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileList[i]));
    }
}

public void createMinHeap() throws IOException {

    for(int i=0;i<No_of_files;i++)
    {
        listString[i]=readers[i].readLine();
        listIndex[i]=i;
    }

    WriteToFile(listString,listIndex);

}

public void WriteToFile(String[] listString,int[] listIndex) throws IOException{

    BuildHeap_forFirstTime(listString, listIndex);
    while(!(listString[0].equals("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz")))
    {
        pw.println(listString[0]);
        listString[0]=readers[listIndex[0]].readLine();

        MinHeapify(listString,listIndex,0);
    }

}
public void BuildHeap_forFirstTime(String[] listString,int[] listIndex){

    for(int i=(No_of_files/2)-1;i>=0;--i)
        MinHeapify(listString,listIndex,i);

}

public void MinHeapify(String[] listString,int[] listIndex,int index){

    int left=index*2 + 1;
    int right=left + 1;
    int smallest=index;
    int HeapSize=No_of_files;
    if(left <= HeapSize-1  && listString[left]!=null &&  (listString[left].compareTo(listString[index])) < 0)
        smallest = left;

    if(right <= HeapSize-1 && listString[right]!=null &&  (listString[right].compareTo(listString[smallest])) < 0)
        smallest=right;



    if(smallest!=index)
    {
        String temp=listString[index];
        listString[index]=listString[smallest];
        listString[smallest]=temp;

        listIndex[smallest]^=listIndex[index];
        listIndex[index]^=listIndex[smallest];
        listIndex[smallest]^=listIndex[index];

        MinHeapify(listString,listIndex,smallest);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation of min heap algorithm for merging k sorted arrays:

```
public class MergeKSorted {

/**
 * helper object to store min value of each array in a priority queue, 
 * the kth array and the index into kth array
 *
 */
static class PQNode implements Comparable<PQNode>{
    int value;
    int kth = 0;
    int indexKth = 0;

    public PQNode(int value, int kth, int indexKth) {
        this.value = value;
        this.kth = kth;
        this.indexKth = indexKth;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(PQNode o) {
        if(o != null) {
            return Integer.valueOf(value).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o.value));
        }
        else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value+" "+kth+" "+indexKth;
    }
}
public static void mergeKSorted(int[][] sortedArrays) {
    int k = sortedArrays.length;
    int resultCtr = 0;
    int totalSize = 0;
    PriorityQueue<PQNode> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        int[] kthArray = sortedArrays[i];
        totalSize+=kthArray.length;
        if(kthArray.length > 0) {
            PQNode temp = new PQNode(kthArray[0], i, 0);
            pq.add(temp); 
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[totalSize];
    while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
        PQNode temp = pq.poll();
        int[] kthArray = sortedArrays[temp.kth];
        result[resultCtr] = temp.value;
        resultCtr++;            
        temp.indexKth++;
        if(temp.indexKth < kthArray.length) {
            temp = new PQNode(kthArray[temp.indexKth], temp.kth, temp.indexKth);
            pq.add(temp);
        }

    }
    print(result);
}

public static void print(int[] a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int v : a) {
        sb.append(v).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[][] sortedA = {
         {3,4,6,9},
         {4,6,8,9,12},
         {3,4,9},
         {1,4,9}    
     };
     mergeKSorted(sortedA);
}

}
```