# Given a sorted array, can we build a sorted array of the sums of all pairs in O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given a sorted array of integers, can we build a sorted array of the sums of all pairs in O(n^2)?

A trivial solution would be to build the array of sums in O(n^2) and then to sort it in O(n^2 (log(n^2)) = O(n^2 logn) time.

Another solution would be to build n sorted arrays of n numbers each - in O(n^2), and merge them in O(n^2 logn) time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055909/algorithm-for-n-way-merge) for example).

Can we do better?

Comment: Um, why would the first solution be O(n^2 (log^2)n) time? Shouldn't it be O(n^2 log(n^2)) ( = O(n^2 log(n)) ) to sort an array of length n^2? Or do you have in mind using something faster than comparison sorting?

Comment: a.k.a. [Sorting X + Y](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P41.html)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat so the problem is over unless we can think of a solution that doesn't exist yet

Comment: @aaronman Yes, the best result known for a comparison sort is sorting with n^2 comparisons in time n^2 log n.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat maybe this can be the first time SO contributes something useful to the world

Comment: @TedHopp: You are correct. I'll fix it.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Thanks! I guess Mortianna was correct - We're doomed.

Comment: @EdHeal yeah 39 year olds get a lot of hw, sorry for ratting you out Lior

Comment: If you don't care about duplicates, you can do it by simply inserting the result into an array at index *k*, where *k* = `i+j` in O(n^2) time, then compacting the array in O(n) time.

Comment: @EdHeal Besides this obviously not being homework (it is an open problem...), the question clearly says what OP has tried.

Comment: @LiorKogan what do you mean, if you want me to delete it thats fine

Comment: @ChrisHeald `i+j` could be a very large number, you can't create or compact an array of that size in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @interjay Can you elaborate? Given that the original array has *n* elements, you just have to allocate an array *n^2* elements in size. You can keep a count of how many new vs override insertions you have, which lets you get the size of the compact array target, which is another simple allocation.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Assuming that by `i+j` in your original comment you meant the sum of each two elements, an array of size n^2 won't be enough because `i+j` can be more than n^2.

Comment: Doh, right; well, you can still allocate an array of the size of `n[-1] + n[-1]` (where -1 means the last element of the array), no? It's not a particularly memory-efficient solution for large values of `n[-1]`, granted, but it is time-efficient assuming memory allocation is O(n).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Sometimes a link is a good answer. I would accept it. I'm afraid that this question will remain open for a long time...

Comment: @ChrisHeald That would give you an O(n^2 + arr[-1]) solution instead of an O(n^2) solution, and arr[-1] could be 2^n for example... This wouldn't be an open problem if there was such a simple solution.

Comment: I realize that the open problem exists and am not pretending to solve it - I'm merely exploring other methods by which the algorithm runtime might be improved by further defining the requirements. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an open problem known in the literature as [Sorting *X* + *Y*](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P41.html). The best result known is an O(n^2 log n)-time algorithm that uses O(n^2) comparisons, due to [Lambert](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759290089X) and [Steiger--Streinu](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190%2894%2900201-9).

Comment: @aaronman Yes, it's possible that there's an O(n^2)-time algorithm, and as far as I know, the existence of such an algorithm would have no "disastrous" consequences the way P = NP would. That there exists an O(n^2)-comparison algorithm makes life difficult for would-be provers of lowerbounds.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: On second thought, maybe X+X (my case) is a special case, where a better solution is already known, or can be achieved?

Comment: @LiorKogan There's a linear-time reduction from the general case to your special case.