# K-way merge operation for merge sort

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, merge, mergesort, array-merge

I have `k` sorted arrays, each with `n` elements, and need to combine them into a single sorted array of `k*n` elements.

How do I implement the merging procedure for merge sort, starting with the first two and the next one and so on?

This is what I have so far.

```
// implementing function to merge arrays (merge procedure for merge sort)   
    public  int[] merge(int[][] array){
        int k = array.length;
        int n = array[0].length;

// final merged array
         int[] mergedArray = new int[k*n];
        return mergedArray;     
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
    Merge obj = new Merge();
int[][] data= new int[][]{{2, 9, 15, 20},
                              {6, 8, 9, 19},
                              {5, 10, 18, 22},
                              {8, 12, 15, 26}};
    int[] mergedArrayTest = obj.merge(data);
    //printArray(mergedArrayTest);
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm for N-way merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055909/algorithm-for-n-way-merge)

Comment: Sounds like you need something similar to [Funnel Sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funnelsort)'s K-Merger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of merging the sub-arrays two at a time, you can merge all `k` at once.

- Make an array of indices into each sub-array. Initially each index is zero.
- On each one of `k*n` iterations to fill the merged array, consider each sub-array's value at its respective index and remember the minimum value. (Skip an index if it has already reached the end of the sub-array.)
- Increment the index that pointed to the minimum value.

This will do it:

```
// k-way merge operation
public int[] merge(int[][] array){
  int k = array.length;
  int n = array[0].length;

  int[] mergedArray = new int[k*n];
  int[] indices = new int[k];
  for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.length; ++i) { 
    int bestValue = -1, bestIndex = -1;
    for (int j = 0; j < indices.length; ++j) { 
      int index = indices[j];
      if (index < n && (bestValue == -1 || array[j][index] < bestValue)) { 
        bestValue = array[j][index];
        bestIndex = j;
      } 
    } 
    mergedArray[i] = bestValue;
    indices[bestIndex] += 1;
  }

  return mergedArray;
}
```

You can make this approach somewhat more efficient by removing indices that have reached the end of their sub-array. However, that still leaves the running time in *O(nk<sup>2</sup>)* because *O(k)* indices are scanned *nk* times.

We can make an asymptotic improvement in running time by storing the indices in a min-heap that uses the value at each index as the key. With *k* indices, the size of the heap never exceeds *k*. In each of *nk* iterations, we pop the heap and push at most one element back on. These heap operations each cost *O(log k)*, so the total running time is *O(nk log k)*.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Candidate {
  int id, index, value;
  Candidate(int id, int index, int value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.index = index;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Heap {
  ArrayList<Candidate> stack = new ArrayList<Candidate>();

  void push(Candidate current) {
    // Add to last position in heap.
    stack.add(current);
    // Bubble up.
    int n = stack.size(),
        pos = n - 1;
    while (pos != 0) {
      int parent = (pos - 1) / 2;
      if (stack.get(parent).value <= current.value) {
        return;
      }
      stack.set(pos, stack.get(parent));
      stack.set(parent, current);
    }
  }

  Candidate pop() {
    // Get top of heap.
    if (stack.size() == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    Candidate result = stack.get(0);
    int n = stack.size();
    if (n == 1) {
      stack.remove(0);
      return result;
    }
    // Swap last element to top.
    stack.set(0, stack.get(--n));
    Candidate current = stack.get(0);
    stack.remove(n);
    // Bubble down.
    int pos = 0;
    while (true) {
      int left = 2 * pos + 1;
      if (left >= n) {
        return result;
      }
      int right = left + 1,
          swapTo = -1;
      if (current.value <= stack.get(left).value) {
        if (right == n || current.value <= stack.get(right).value) {
          return result;
        }
        swapTo = right;
      } else {
        if (right != n && stack.get(left).value > stack.get(right).value) {
          swapTo = right;
        } else {
          swapTo = left;
        }
      }
      stack.set(pos, stack.get(swapTo));
      stack.set(swapTo, current);
      pos = swapTo;
    }
  }
}

public class Merge {

  // k-way merge
  public  int[] merge(int[][] array){
    int k = array.length;
    int n = array[0].length;

    int[] mergedArray = new int[k*n];

    // Initialize heap with subarray number, index, and value.
    Heap indexHeap = new Heap();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
      indexHeap.push(new Candidate(i, 0, array[i][0]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.length; ++i) {
      // Get the minimum value from the heap and augment the merged array.
      Candidate best = indexHeap.pop();
      mergedArray[i] = best.value;
      // Increment the index. If it's still valid, push it back onto the heap.
      if (++best.index < array[best.id].length) {
        best.value = array[best.id][best.index];
        indexHeap.push(best);
      }
    }

    // Print out the merged array for testing purposes.
    for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.length; ++i) {
      System.out.print(mergedArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return mergedArray;
  }

  public static void main(String[]args){
    Merge merge = new Merge();
    int[][] data= new int[][]{{2, 9, 15, 20},
                              {6, 8, 9, 19},
                              {5, 10, 18, 22},
                              {8, 12, 15, 26}};
    int[] mergedArrayTest = merge.merge(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG!!!! it's understandable and it's working now for which i have been stressing so hard , confusing with vague understanding of everything but getting stuck everytime  I start to code.

Comment: Now i will start trying the Divide and conquer strategy to do the same . Most probably will need your help again :)

Comment: I wasn't sure what you actual mean by accepting answers? Do i have to click on somewhere or just comment about what you replied?

Comment: Click on the check mark beside my answer. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: This requires time proportional to k for each element of a k- way merge. If you put the current head of each list in a min heap, then the cost is only log k per step, which is a big deal if k is reasonably big.

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo You have coerced the OP to accept your answer for an optimized version, I expected you would at least update with a heap-based O(nk log k) version. What a bummer.

Comment: I have added a min-heap implementation to my answer.