# How to sort n dimensional list into one list with efficient way

Tags: python, list

```
input [[1,4,5],[1,3,4],[2,6]]
```

```
output [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6]
```

I have done a baby way by putting each value in to one process list which takes 2 loops
and another loop for sorting

Is there any way to do it within O(n) or as fast as possible or not with using any function

```
def sortmerge(inputList):
    processList = []
    sortedList= []
    for i in range(len(inputList)):
        for j in range(len(inputList[i])):
            processList.append(inputList[i][j])
    # processList.sort()
    while processList:
        minimum = processList[0] 
        for x in processList: 
            if x < minimum:
                minimum = x
        sortedList.append(minimum)
        processList.remove(minimum)
    return sortedList
```

Comment: What have you attempted? What is "baby way"

Comment: Just do a n-way merge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055909/algorithm-for-n-way-merge

Comment: There's no sorting algorithm with `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: Are the lists that you want to merge sorted?

Comment: Are the inner lists guaranteed to already be sorted…?

Comment: Are the values always integers?

Comment: update* my way on post //  
sub list might not be sorted at first

Comment: The sub lists might *not* be sorted?! Then you're asking for a general O(n) sorting algorithm, which is pie in the sky.

Comment: Unless you can make more guarantees about your values, the most efficient in terms of speed and programmer time (not necessarily big-O though) is probably `sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable(input))`.

Comment: Do I need to import anything?
```
return sorted(chain.from_iterable(inputList))
NameError: name 'chain' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604218/how-to-sort-n-dimensional-list-into-one-list-with-efficient-way#comment119493550_67604218), the sub-lists might not be sorted. Therefore, *O(n)* is not possible since sorting is required, but you can get *O(n log n)* by flattening then sorting.

```
from itertools import chain

inputList = [[1, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4], [2, 6]]
print(sorted(chain.from_iterable(inputList)))  # -> [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

([`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) uses [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which is *O(n log n)*, and chaining is *O(n)*.)

There might be faster ways than this if you can make more guarantees about your input data. For example, if only a few sublists might be unsorted, it could be faster to sort them, then merge.

*<sub>Due credit to [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) for posting this solution in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604218/how-to-sort-n-dimensional-list-into-one-list-with-efficient-way#comment119493627_67604218)</sub>*