# What is the fastest (insert speed) way to achieve a prioritized collection of arrays in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, sortedlist, jump-list

I am writing a specific priority queue. Its structure needs to be something as follows:

```
Priority(<int>)    Data(List<Object>)
1                  a, b, g, h
3                  c, d, j
4                  k
10                 e, f, i
```

I need to be able to efficiently find if a list exists for a given priority; if not, create the list and add the message, otherwise append the message to the existing list.

I have written a red-black tree, but this seems like overkill for this, and may not be the fastest solution. It also has the drawback of not being able to easily grab the messages by priority, which I need to be able to do once the writing has been completed.

I thought about Dictionary, but unless I am mistaken, it doesn't have a simple way to say "if the key __ exists, give me the value corresponding to it, otherwise give me null". Or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

My current implementation is to have 32 fixed lists. The applicable list is added to and the applicable bit set in a 32-bit flag. I use De Bruijn's algorithm to get the LSB. This is efficient, but is adding other complexity that I want to alleviate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net might be relevant

Comment: What's the range of the priority values? ie. will you only have priorities 1-10, or do you have the whole range of int-values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use `Dictionary<int,List<object>>`

```
public void Add(int priority,object data)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(priority))
       dictionary[priority].Add(data);
    else
       dictionary.Add(priority,new List<object>{data});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A SortedDictionary would fill the job. Just use TryGetValue() to conditionally find the list.

Answer (score 3):

Hm, what's wrong with `Dictionary` as the underlying container? You get O(1) access/insertion time on average, instead of O(log n) with rb-trees. Just wrap `Dictionary` according to your needs, for example:

```
internal public class PriorityQueue<TValue> 
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<TValue>> mDict;

    // only Add, TryGetValue shown...
    public void Add(int pPriority, TValue pInput) 
    {
        List<TValue> tTmp;
        if (mDict.TryGetValue(pPriority, tTmp)) 
        {
            tTmp.Add(pInput);
        } 
        else 
        {
            mDict.Add(pPriority, new List<TValue>{ pInput });
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(int pPriority, out List<TValue>) 
    {
        // obvious...
    }
}
```

Comment: Strangely, this solution is slightly slower than the one I initially accepted when running in debug mode, but faster when running outside of VS. I wonder why.

Comment: The first solution requires two dictionary lookups inside of `Add`: one for `ContainsKey` and one when using the indexer. The above solution does only one lookup (using `TryGetValue`). Theroretically, since both are O(1) on average there shouldn't be a difference, but you get the overhead of an additional method call and that O(1) is, hm well, just theory. Regarding the difference between debug and release modes: well, I'm just speculating, but I could imagine that there is some additional code injected when using `ref` parameters...