# How to make a sortedlist sort reversely? Do I have to customize a IComparer?

Tags: c#, sortedlist

In a sortedlist queue, queue.value[0] gives the corresponding value of a min key. what if i would like to make that it gives the value of a max key?

Do i have to rewrite the icomparer?

Comment: If you are only interrested in the maximum key, the list is big and performance is key, you should check out priority queues (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net)

Comment: @larsm - I thought priority queues were implemented in C# using sortedlist/sortedddirectionary. Is it not true?

Comment: That would be a bad implementation. A priority queue only requires the first item top be the min/max element, it has no requirements on the remaining items in the list. By exploiting this, a priority queue is potentially a much more efficient data container than a fully sorted list/dictionary. Typically, priority queues are implemented using heaps (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Naive_implementations)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you have to rewrite the comparer

example for string as key: (just exchanged `x.CompareTo(y)` with `y.CompareTo(x)` )

```
private class InvertedComparer : IComparer<String>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return y.CompareTo(x);
        }
    }
```

and the call:

```
SortedList<string, Object> list = new SortedList<string, Object>(new InvertedComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Reversing_the_Contents_of_a_Sorted_List) to an article that implements a `ReversibleSortedList`. This allows for changing the sort direction.

In case you always want reversed sort behavior without the ability to change it on demand, I'd try the constructor that [accepts an IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a8xew6.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Array.Reverse()` in some simple cases.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Input array.
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };

    // Print.
    foreach (int value in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Reverse.
    Array.Reverse(array);

    // Print.
    foreach (int value in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Reverse again.
    Array.Reverse(array);

    // Print.
    foreach (int value in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    }
}
```

*** Output ***

```
1
2
3

3
2
1

1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just invert any existing IComparers. Something like:

```
public static IComparer<T> Invert<T>(this IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return Comparer<T>.Create((x, y) => comparer.Compare(y, x));
}
```

And use your regular comparer. For e.g.

```
new SortedList<,>(myShinyComparer.Invert());
```