# Starvation free Priority Queue C#

Tags: c#, priority-queue

I am looking for an implementation of a priority queue that prevents starvation.

Comment: Related non-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net some of the answers there talk about starvation.

Comment: -1 for wanting codez. No explanation for why, what they might have tried, any errors they have.

Comment: Actually, @Alastair, the OP simply asked for an implementation. This could mean a library or a tutorial somewhere. And generally there's no need to ask for an explanation for basic data structures. This is like asking, "does anyone out there know of a good red-black tree library in C#?" Perfectly valid (if perhaps not well-researched).

Comment: @Chris: Fair enough, but it also showed no research. I'm all for asking a question regarding a data structure, but the question showed no initiative and no research. Did the OP google the question first? What ideas did they have on how this could be implemented? I don't think the question contributes or helps the community in it's current form.