# Heap data structure in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Priority queue in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net)

Is there an implementation of the Heap data structure in .Net?

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)

Comment: why, what you need this for would help us

Comment: [Google shows a lot of results](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=heap+.net&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&sa=X&ei=6h2QT9rZL--QiAesu5DyAw&ved=0CBgQvwUoAQ&q=heap+data+structure+.net&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5382211b2869208a&biw=1433&bih=728)

Comment: A simple binary heap I created a while back: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789

Comment: @Henk Holterman because I was not sure if heap was the same as priority queue

Comment: A heap is not the same thing as a priority queue. A heap is one way to implement a priority queue, but there are many others such as skip lists, balanced binary trees, etc.

Comment: As of January 2021, .Net Core added a PriorityQueue implementation. The actual commit to the repo and the API can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/826aa4f7844fd3d48784025ec6d47010867baab4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This class I've been working on might be useful for you. Obviously I give you no guarantees.

```
public sealed class FibonacciHeap<TKey, TValue>
{
    readonly List<Node> _root = new List<Node>();
    int _count;
    Node _min;

    public void Push(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Insert(new Node {
            Key = key,
            Value = value
        });
    }       

    public KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Peek()
    {
        if (_min == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(_min.Key, _min.Value);
    }       

    public KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Pop()
    {
        if (_min == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var min = ExtractMin();
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(min.Key, min.Value);
    }

    void Insert(Node node)
    {
        _count++;
        _root.Add(node);
        if (_min == null)
        {
            _min = node;
        }
        else if (Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(node.Key, _min.Key) < 0)
        {
            _min = node;
        }
    }

    Node ExtractMin()
    {
        var result = _min;
        if (result == null)
            return null;
        foreach (var child in result.Children)
        {
            child.Parent = null;
            _root.Add(child);
        }
        _root.Remove(result);
        if (_root.Count == 0)
        {
            _min = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _min = _root[0];
            Consolidate();
        }
        _count--;
        return result;
    }

    void Consolidate()
    {
        var a = new Node[UpperBound()];
        for (int i = 0; i < _root.Count; i++)
        {
            var x = _root[i];
            var d = x.Children.Count;
            while (true)
            {   
                var y = a[d];
                if (y == null)
                    break;                  
                if (Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(x.Key, y.Key) > 0)
                {
                    var t = x;
                    x = y;
                    y = t;
                }
                _root.Remove(y);
                i--;
                x.AddChild(y);
                y.Mark = false;
                a[d] = null;
                d++;
            }
            a[d] = x;
        }
        _min = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            var n = a[i];
            if (n == null)
                continue;
            if (_min == null)
            {
                _root.Clear();
                _min = n;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(n.Key, _min.Key) < 0)
                {
                    _min = n;
                }
            }
            _root.Add(n);
        }
    }

    int UpperBound()
    {
        return (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(_count, (1.0 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2.0)) + 1;
    }

    class Node
    {
        public TKey Key;
        public TValue Value;
        public Node Parent;
        public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
        public bool Mark;

        public void AddChild(Node child)
        {
            child.Parent = this;
            Children.Add(child);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("({0},{1})", Key, Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know how this performs when compared to a simple binary heap. Have you done any comparisons?

Comment: I think the questioner wants to know  if there is a .Net framework class for Heap data structure.