# Getting the lowest value of a List<Struct.int>

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, a-star

I've got a `struct` which contains a few `int` and `bool` members, and I'm looking to obtain the lowest value from the list (actually making an A* Search based Path Finder).

Basically, my object looks like this:

```
    public struct Tile
    {
        public int id;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cost;
        public bool walkable;
        public int distanceLeft;
        public int parentid;
    }
```

And I want to get the item with the lowest distanceLeft. The list is declared like so:

```
        List<Structs.Tile> openList = new List<Structs.Tile>();
```

And values are assigned in this manner:

```
        while (pathFound == null)
        {
            foreach (Structs.Tile tile in map)
            {
                foreach (Structs.Tile tile1 in getSurroundingTiles(Current))
                {
                    if (tile1.x == tile.x && tile1.y == tile.y)
                    {
                        Structs.Tile curTile = tile1;
                        curTile.parentid = Current.id;
                        curTile.distanceLeft = (Math.Abs(tile.x - goalx) + Math.Abs(tile.y - goaly));
                        if (curTile.distanceLeft == 0)
                        {
                            pathFound = true;
                        }
                        openList.Add(curTile);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (Structs.Tile tile in openList)
            {

            }
        }
```

If I had to guess I'd say this is either very difficult or far more complex than I'm making it sound, or incredibly easy and I'm just confused.

I did think about scrolling through the list and comparing each item to its lower counterpart, but that seems unreasonable considering the age we're in, it just seems there would be a simpler way. I don't care for the order of the list, as I am assigning each item an index from which I can call it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have a look at LINQ.

Comment: Why do you use a struct? It does consume about 28 bytes which is much bigger than the pointer size of 4/8 bytes. Every method which does consume your struct needs to carry 28 bytes. If it would be class the comparison would be much faster.

Comment: It probably is a duplicate mbeckish, but I don't know Linq well enough to know that this is a Linq function, so my sincere apologies for this. I'd still like to retain this thread for a while though, as it does contain a response which I think could be useful to some people (others who may not know of Linq or the association referenced here).

Comment: Alois Kraus - I am not entirely aware of the pros and cons behind using a class, though I would've thought that declaring a new instance of a class would be more of a job than a new instance of a struct? If not, let me know and I'll remember this for future reference. Thanks massively for your advise, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: There is a little article explaining this stuff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not one LINQ extension method that returns the object with a minimum value, but you can write one yourself. The following class does what you want on any non-empty enumerable:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static TSource MinOf<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, int> selector)
    {
        // Get the enumerator.
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The source sequence is empty.");

        // Take the first value as a minimum.
        int minimum = selector(enumerator.Current);
        TSource current = enumerator.Current;

        // Go through all other values...
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            int value = selector(enumerator.Current);
            if (value < minimum)
            {
                // A new minimum was found. Store it.
                minimum = value;
                current = enumerator.Current;
            }
        }

        // Return the minimum value.
        return current;
    }
}
```

Put it in a file in your project and call it like this:

```
openList.MinOf(tile => tile.distanceLeft);
```

This is more efficient than ordering the entire sequence (using `OrderBy`) and then taking the first value (using `First`).

Comment: Thanks, will this method return the object itself though, or just the int which is stored in the object? I assume by looking at it, the object?

Comment: No it returned the int. I updated the answer with something that will return the object.

Comment: Thanks, this looks really complex but I'll take a while to understand it. It seems this is the "correct" way to proceed, so thanks a lot dude!

Comment: @JimMischel `Min` returns an int. He want the object.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers explain how to do this with LINQ - however, they are all `O(n)` or slower.  Using one of those methods will *significantly* slow down your pathfinding algorithm.

Instead, you **should be using a proper data structure**.  Rather than a list, you should be storing your nodes in a **Priority Queue** to get *(and remove)* the minimum in `O(log n)`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net) for a list of priority queues in .Net.

Comment: That rather depends on how you normally use the collection. If you want to index into it, a priority queue is going to be a rather poor choice of data structure.

Comment: @Jim: He stated in the question he wants to use it for [A\*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Description)

Comment: Ahhh ... missed that. Then a priority queue is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `Tile` with the lowest `distanceLeft`, try this:

```
Tile tile = openList.OrderByAscending(t => t.distanceLeft).First();
```

**Edit:**

Doing this will return an `IEnumerable<Tile>` which will be sorted in ascending order - `openList` itself will not be modified.

Comment: Will this modify the order of the list? If so, I think the Linq option may be favourable, I know I mentioned that I don't mind modifying the order, but I'd rather not for the sake of resources and what not, it seems it may be somewhat wasteful to do this. I greatly appreciate your response, nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: It does not modify the input list. Instead it creates some memory structure that sorts the entire list which is then all discarded except for the first element.

Comment: It does seem more memory intensive than the alternative method here, but as I said I appreciate the input, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or, if for some reason you can't use LINQ:

```
int lowest = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < openList.Count; ++i)
{
    if (openList[i].distanceLeft < openList[lowest].distanceLeft)
    {
        lowest = i;
    }
}
// lowest contains the index of the item with the lowest 'distanceLeft' value.
// You can return the item itself by indexing into the list.
var lowestItem = openList[lowest];
```

Comment: This returns the minimum value, not the object with the minimum value

Comment: Just to give a bit more clarification as to why you can't use Min() in this situation: `Min()` returns the object, but compares the objects itself (you can't specify a selector). `Min(lambda)` returns the datatype that the lambda selects, which in this case is an int.

Comment: Actually, it was returning the index of the item with the minimum value. Now it returns the item itself.

Comment: @gunr2171: Yeah, saw that. My bad. It's odd that the interface is written that way.