# JAVA to C# conversion - PriorityQueue

Tags: c#, java, list

This question was posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881110/java-to-c-sharp-conversion) by a team member but was closed due to the community not having enough information.

Here's my attempt to revive such a question being, **How would I go about converting this java extract into C#?**

Java Extract:

```
PriorityQueue<PuzzleNode> openList = new PriorityQueue<PuzzleNode>
           (1,
            new Comparator<PuzzleNode>(){
                public int compare(PuzzleNode a, PuzzleNode b){
                    if (a.getPathCost() > b.getPathCost())
                        return 1;
                    else if (a.getPathCost() < b.getPathCost())
                        return -1;
                    else
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            );
```

A sortedList has been thought about but to no avail as I'm unsure how to code it.

I've also tried creating a standard list with a method:

```
List<PuzzleNode> openList = new List<PuzzleNode>();

//Method to sort the list
public int CompareFCost(PuzzleNode a, PuzzleNode b)
        {
            if (a.getPathCost() > b.getPathCost())
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (a.getPathCost() > b.getPathCost())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }//end CompareFCost
```

and then calling: openList.Sort(CompareFCost); at appropriate locations, however this doesn't work.

**What the code is used for?**
It orders the objects 'PuzzleNode' depending on a score (pathCost) I have set else where in the program. A while loop then operates and pulls the first object from the list. The list needs to be ordered otherwise an object with a higher pathCost could be chosen and the while loop will run for longer. The objective is to pull the lower pathCost from the list.

I ask for a conversion because it works in Java & the rest of the code has pretty much originated from Java.

Any takers? If you need further info I'm happy to discuss it further.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net I think the only problem there is an alternative to a PriorityQueue, which is quite different from a simple ordered list.

Comment: What's the final intent of this? Did you know you can use `LinQ` to do all sorts of `IEnumerable<T>` related operations? Also, what's the difference between the java's `PriorityQueue<T>` and a regular `List<T>`?

Comment: @HighCore - Priority queues allow efficient access to and removal of the minimum element.

Comment: @Lee and by "minimum element" you mean...?

Comment: Please check edited question which states what it is needed for. I didn't know that, nor do I know how to go about using them at the moment, I'll look into it.

Comment: X to Y conversion questions are almost always closed

Comment: The minimum element is the element with the lowest/highest priority, in this case. Most priority queues achieve this in O(logN) or O(1) time, while guaranteeing interesting orders of complexity for the rest of the operations (insertion, deletion, etc).

Comment: @HighCore - In this case it appears to be the node with the minimum path cost. If the elements in the queue don't have a natural ordering then a custom comparator is required to compare elements.

Comment: Assuming you use a List<PuzzleNode> and are just ordering based on the PathCost, you could use linq: `var orderedList = openList.OrderBy(node => node.getPathCost())` (`.OrderByDescending` if it needs to go the other way). Or, if you want more control over the comparison, look here at the "order by comparer" examples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could misappropriate a SortedList something like this:

```
var openList=new SortedList<PuzzleNode,PuzzleNode>(
    //assumes .Net4.5 for Comparer.Create
    Comparer<PuzzleNode>.Create((a,b)=>{
        if (a.getPathCost() > b.getPathCost())
                    return 1;
                else if (a.getPathCost() < b.getPathCost())
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;

    }));
openList.Add(new PuzzleNode());
foreach(var x in openList.Keys)
{
    //ordered enumeration
}
var firstItem = openList.Dequeue();
```

by creating some extension methods to make things a little more queue-like

```
static class SortedListExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this SortedList<T,T> list,T item)
    {
        list.Add(item,item);
    }
    public static T Dequeue<T>(this SortedList<T,T> list)
    {
        var item=list.Keys.First();
        list.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }
    //and so on...
}
```

TBH, I'd probably go for @valverij's answer in the comment to your original question, but if the cost of repeated sorting is prohibitive, this may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> **What the code is used for?** It orders the objects 'PuzzleNode'
>   depending on a score (pathCost) I have set else where in the program.
>   A while loop then operates and pulls the first object from the list.
>   The list needs to be ordered otherwise an object with a higher
>   pathCost could be chosen and the while loop will run for longer. The
>   objective is to pull the lower pathCost from the list.

- 1: There's [`LinQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb397897.aspx) for that. You don't usually do any of these things in C#, because LinQ does it for you.

  - It orders the objects 'PuzzleNode' depending on a score (pathCost)

    That's Achieved with LinQ's `Enumerable.OrderBy()` Extension:

    ```
    //Assuming PathCost is a property of a primitive type (int, double, string, etc)
    var orderedlist = list.OrderBy(x => x.PathCost);
    ```
  - The objective is to pull the lower pathCost from the list.

    That's achieved using LinQ's `Enumerable.Min()` or `Enumerable.Max()` extensions.

    ```
    //Same assumption as above.
    var puzzlewithlowestpath = list.Min(x => x.PathCost);
    ```

---

here goes my rant about java being incomplete compared to C# because it lacks something like `LinQ`, but I will not do any more ranting in StackOverflow by now.

---

Another thing I wanted to mention is that if you are coding in C#, you'd better use [C# Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), where [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) are ProperCased:

```
public int PathCost {get;set;}
//or double or whatever
```

instead of:

```
public int getPathCost()
public int setPathCost()
```