# C# - Dynamic priority list

Tags: c#, design-patterns, priority-queue

I want to implement a priority list with the following requirements:

1. It should have a priority method/property which is dynamic (i.e. I can change item priority after adding it).
2. I need the ability to add/remove every item.
3. Performance is a real issue so I want the implementation that doesn’t sort when item is added or in priority change.
4. I prefer to use C# build-in component as is (if exists, if not then with minor modifications).

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Does it need to be concurrent?  Does it need to be blocking?

Comment: This may not be a queue but my requirements are very clear. So far i am using a list, and sort it in every "event" (i.e item added/priority change)

Comment: How many priority levels? - If only a few, you could use a priority-indexed vector of lists.

Comment: Martin - this queue is being updated from one source - does it answer your question?

Comment: So how many priority levels?

Comment: @YossiDahari - no.  Are the single updater and consumer/s run by different threads and, if so, do the consumers need to block, waiting for entries?

Comment: The priority is a machine utility - this would be an integer 0-100. only one thread exists for my purposes (and single updater).

Comment: Is 101 lists out of the question?  'Push' would be very quick, 'Pop' slower since it means iterating the lists from the highest-prio down until a non-zero count found, (possibly inside a lock).  I guess that the speed for delete/prioChange operations would depend on the length of the lists.  That's all I can think of if anything except an insertion sort by prio index needs to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use a standard `List<T>` that should give you everything you have asked for if you use `priority == index.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about priority lists or queues but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net?rq=1) seems to give a lot of useful information (even though it was closed).