# Best collection for keep objects sorted and remove by key

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I have events and timestamp of the events. I want to keep objects sorted on timestamp. And i want to remove old objects every minutes. Since objects already sorted on timestamp i think  RemoveLesserThenKey like function will work best.

I checked sortedlist but it seems it doesnt have such function. Can you give me any advice?

Do i have to write my own sorted list?

EDIT:
1-Events do not come according to time.
2-I want a collection to use sorting structure(Like BST) to remove objects.

Comment: kind of sounds like you just want a Queue

Comment: does the timestamp change over time or is it immutable?  Are objects added to the collection in timestamp order?

Comment: I added a comment and yes time is immuteable.

Comment: yes object will be sorted on timestamp. i edited question again.

Comment: It sounds like you want a priority queue, there isn't an implementation in the BCL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net in regards to priority queue. OrderedBag and OrderedSet classes may be what you need.

Comment: As the events do not come according to time, could it happen that an event arrives with a timestamp earlier than the old objects which have been deleted?

Comment: I already check this situation somewhere else. But, they will be deleted next minute anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) is Your friend

Comment: Since OP seemed like he wanted a specific function to remove lesser keys, I'd just like to add that this could be accomplished simply by iterating through the keys and removing entries after a certain point where items are considered old. He could have also accomplished this with a `SortedList` by removing entries starting at a certain index, but since he is working with data that is not coming in sorted the `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is the best choice between the two.

Comment: Yes, I can remove objects until a condition has met. Since my condition is only about key values, there should be faster way to remove objects. Just removing left branch of the BST kind of way.

Comment: Does this count as link only? More details to flesh the answer out as to _how_ to use this would be good

Answer (score 0):

I think you would best off writing your own sorted linked list for this.  Insertions could be done in worst case O(n) time and removing all nodes below a certain threshold would be a simple linear time operation.

As you suggested you could also use a BST.  You'd just have to remember to set a new root every time you did a batch removal.

Edit: In thinking about this, a BST would wind up very unbalanced to the right after a few insert/delete rounds.  It may not offer much in the way of time savings over a linked list.