# Microsoft Collections for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, collections, f#, priority-queue

.NET comes with some built in collections (stack, queue, dictionary, list etc.) but others common collections, like priority queues, are missing. There are many third party collection libraries on NuGet but I was wondering if there is an official Microsoft one (like the BCL immutable collections now called `System.Collections.Immutable`) library with things like (mutable) priorities queues?

EDIT: Important clarification (comment by @rmunn):

> This question is not asking to recommend a library for X, it is asking
>   a factual question, "Are there any official Microsoft libraries for
>   X?"

Comment: I searched hard but was not able to find one. But to be honest it's easy to implement yourself, and if you don't want to - it's easy to verify third party implementation makes sense if you have some fears about that.

Comment: There is no official Microsoft PriorityQueue implementation.  Is there some reason you don't want to use a 3rd party version?

Comment: @BrandonKramer: I'm happy to use proprietary third party libraries if there is no official Microsoft solution but I just wanted to make sure there is no official solution before going "off road".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Priority queue in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I can understand preferring official solutions to 3rd party ones.

Comment: This question should not have been marked off-topic. It is not asking to recommend a library for X, it is asking a factual question, "Are there any *official* Microsoft libraries for X?". I've voted to reopen it, for that reason.

Comment: Of course, that's still asking to "find" an "off-site resource", so I'm not sure that it meets the criteria for reopening...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**.NET 6+:** .NET 6 adds a [System.Collections.Generic.PriorityQueue<TElement,TPriority>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0) class. And FWIW it is open-source and [implemented in c#](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs).

**Earlier .NET Core versions and .NET Framework:** Microsoft has written (and shared online) [2 internal PriorityQueue classes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=priorityqueue) within the .NET Framework. You could use their code.

See also: [Priority queue in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/priority-queue-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already looked at it, but the `System.Collections.Specialized`namespace contains quite some hidden gems.
Also the `System.Linq` namespace can be worth a look.