# How to use set data structure in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and writing C# scripts in notepad++.
Can someone tell me how to use set data structure or in general point me to documentation where I can find details about data structures like priority queue that I can use with C# script in unity.

I am using something like

```
SortedSet my_Set1 = new SortedSet();
```

And the error is :

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SortedSet' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Priority queue in .Net (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/102398/7111561)

Comment: I have changed the tags, thank you.

Comment: maybe checkout [`System.Collection.Generic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic) and simply use the kind of structure you need for your case .. and don't forgtet to include the `using` statement on top of your script `using System.Collection.Generic;`

Comment: I figured out the problem it was with scripting runtime version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay now the problem is sorted. The problem was with Scripting Runtime Version. Changing scripting runtime version to .Net.4.x works.

Following are the steps -

Edit -> Project Setting -> Player Setting -> Other setting -> Configuration -> Scripting Runtime version

and change it to .Net 4.x